# CakePHP Ajax pagination problems

Tags: ajax, cakephp, pagination

I am using cakephp 2.2.2 and I want to create a simple ajax pagination. I am following this ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#ajax-pagination ) and I cant seem to get it working right. When I load the page sometimes it uses ajax sometimes it doesnt, in IE 10 I also get something strange like the whole menu collapsing into div that was set to be updated.

Here is what I did:

1. Put `echo $this->Html->script('jquery');` inside the `<head>` of my layout file.
2. Included RequestHandler component and Js helper in my controller.
3. put this in the beginning of my view file:

   $this->Paginator->options(array( 'update' => '#content', 'evalScripts' => true ));
4. put this in the bottom of layout file just before `</body>`: 
   `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();`
5. Then i normally used paginator like this:

   echo $this->Paginator->sort('id');

Can somebody tell me if I am missing something or what is wrong because I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I also had same issues with ajax in pagination.

I found a temporary solution.
In the controller function, add following code to set a flag variable.

```
 if($this->request->is('ajax')){
        $this->set('paginate',true);
    }
```

Then in the view, you need to hide the section other than under #content div.

```
<?php if(!isset($paginate)):
    // Code above # content div including the start of div
endif:?>

Pagination code inside the content div

<?php if(!isset($paginate)):
    // Code below # content div including content of div
endif:?>
```

P.S. The logic is that when pagination is done, other parts will not be shown in the paged view.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that in a day or two when i get my hands on this project again, but do you think this fixes the problem that one time browser reloads (like there is no ajax), and the other time it doesnt reload (like there is ajax). This occurs only using pagination, every other ajax stuff I configure and use myself works perfectly.
Or this helps only for the part where I sometimes get messed up  divs one in nother?

Answer (score 0):

Just move this code from your `view` file to your `layout` :

```
$this->Paginator->options(array( 'update' => '#content', 'evalScripts' => true ));
```